# mySQL stored function problem

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I'm defining a simple stored function which works fine in my local testing database, but when I try to create it on the "real" server, it just doesn't get added to the 'proc'-table. I'm getting no errors or anything, it just doesn't get added (hence, the function can't be used of course).

Both servers are using the same version, and I can't see any differences between the structures of the 'proc'-tables.

Any ideas? A permission problem?

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried to create the function in the mysql-shell instead of in phpMyAdmin, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking in the error log file: usually /mysql.err on Windows, /hostname.err on Unix.

To debug permissions issues, run "SELECT * FROM user where host='hostname' and user='username'".  More information on this [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm)